# How to select Postgresql record based on calculated json value with Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres table with 2 columns that I use in a query:

```
start_date_detail: date 
flex: jsonb
```

Example of the flex field:

```
{
    "communication": [
        {
            "remind_on": "mxmw@cxla.nl",
            "type": "email",
            "remind_date": -150
        },
        {
            "remind_on": "+31612345678",
            "type": "sms",
            "remind_date": -360
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to select all records that have a remind date that lies in the last week, so (pseudo code):

```
(now() - 1-week) < (start_date_detail + remind_date) < now()
```

How can I realise that with sqlalchemy?

Because it's a calculated value in the query, I don't know how to do this.
In postgres I cam up with this, and that works:

```sql
SELECT * FROM time_item 
WHERE 
    (start_date_detail + INTERVAL '1 second' * (flex->'communication'->0->>'remind_date')::numeric <= NOW())
    OR (start_date_detail + INTERVAL '1 second' * (flex->'communication'->1->>'remind_date')::numeric <= NOW())
```

How to put this in sqlalchemy?

One more thing:
In the above query I add every communication item to the where clause. How can I make this more flexible? That is that I don't need to put a where clause for every communication item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to expand the array to a set of `jsonb` elements that you could then use in predicates. SQLAlchemy supports function expressions as selectables through use of [alias](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias). Using a model such as

```
In [4]: class TimeItem(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'time_item'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     start_date_detail = Column(Date)
   ...:     flex = Column(JSONB)
   ...:
```

the query could look like

```
In [39]: session.query(TimeItem).\
    ...:     select_from(TimeItem,
    ...:                 func.jsonb_array_elements(TimeItem.flex['communication']).
    ...:                     alias('comm')).\
    ...:     filter((TimeItem.start_date_detail +
    ...:             timedelta(seconds=1) *
    ...:             column('comm', type_=JSONB)['remind_date'].
    ...:                 astext.
    ...:                 cast(Integer)).
    ...:                     between(func.now() - timedelta(weeks=1),
    ...:                             func.now())).\
    ...:     all()
```

You can then tweak the predicates to suit your needs – I've tried to follow your examples in that `remind_date` is interpreted as offset seconds to `start_date_detail`, compared between a week preceding now and now. When querying entities such as `TimeItem` SQLAlchemy does its own deduplication based on object identities, so the query can omit SQL side DISTINCT, moving the array elements in an EXISTS subquery expression, or such.

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much, give me a few days to use it and I will come back to it, but I think I understand what is going on

Comment: The query works perfect, thanks a lot. I still find it hard to master the JSON query materie.  Would you advice put an index on the start_date_detail and remind_date? And would this look like?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot index an expression that uses derived values from set returning functions, such as `jsonb_array_elements()`. If there's there are known limits to `start_date_detail` and `remind_date` combination, you could use a range on `start_date_detail` as a "coarse" predicate that's indexable.